# Passing parameters to view

Tags: twig, symfony5

I have a small problem of which I do not understand the origin. I would like to filter an array but I have an error when I want to send parameters.
The error says

> Variable "date" does not exist.

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ path('entree_filter',{'fournisseur': fournisseur, 'date': date}) }}">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Date</label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Fournisseur</label>
                        </div>
                        <select class="custom-select" name="fournisseur"> 
                            {% for fournisseurs in fournisseur %}
                                <option value="{{ fournisseurs.id }}">{{ fournisseurs.frnNom }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="filtre" value="Filtrer" style="font-size: 14px">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/{date}/{fournisseur}", name="entree_filter")
 */
public function entreeFilter(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, $fournisseur, $date): Response
{
    $repository = $doctrine->getRepository(Entree::class);
    $entree = $repository->findEntreeByFrn($fournisseur,$date);
    return $this->render('entree/index.html.twig', [
        'entrees' =>$entree
    ]);
}
```

And my repository

```
 public function findEntreeByFrn($dates, $fournisseur){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->andWhere('e.fournisseurId :idFrn and e.entr_date: dates')
        ->setParameter('idFrn', $fournisseur)
        ->setParameter('dates', $dates)
        // ->setParameters(['idFrn' => $fournisseur, 'dates'=> $date])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult
    ;
}
```

Comment: You would still need to pass the variables `date` and `fournisseur` to your view/template from the function `entreeFilter`

Answer (score 0):

Now I see, you don't give $date as argument to the twig. Use that.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{date}/{fournisseur}", name="entree_filter")
 */
public function entreeFilter(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, $fournisseur, $date): Response
{
    $repository = $doctrine->getRepository(Entree::class);
    $entree = $repository->findEntreeByFrn($fournisseur,$date);
    return $this->render('entree/index.html.twig', [
        'entrees' => $entree,
        'date' => $date
    ]);
}
```

Comment: it returns the same error

Comment: Provide screenshot of the error for more details.

Comment: Then you are adjusting the wrong controller function

Comment: Is that controller which render the template you provided ?

Comment: The error is in index.html.twig

Comment: the problem is that the 'date' parameter in the index.html.twig is not recognized